# Why am I seeing in 3d?

Tags: stereo-3d, windows-8.1

I just installed the Stanley parable as a mod, and upon first launching the game, I've got the red-blue tinges on the corner, like the game is enabled for the red-blue 3d glasses. I didn't enable this, is there some way I can disable this feature, maybe a Source engine solution?

I didn't realize this was a factor, but I did just install Windows 8.1.

Comment: Strangely enough I had an identical problem after installing windows 8.1 the other day - turned out to be the newest nvidia drivers enabled stereoscopic 3d by default. Uninstalling the stereoscopic 3d components resolved my issue

Comment: Kalina. I just installed 8.1 as well. Put that as an answer, I'm trying it now, it'll get an upvote at least, and if it works, the checkmark

Comment: retag this to include windows 8.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had an identical issue when I upgraded Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 - as part of the installation process the drivers for my nVidia graphics card were reinstalled, which included the stereoscopic 3D drivers and defaulted them to enabled. In my instance I got the 3D effect in Payday 2 rather than the game you're trying to play.

I resolved this issue by uninstalling the nVidia stereoscopic 3D drivers through add/remove programs. If you're actually ever going to use stereoscopic 3D you can disable it by unchecking the "Enable stereoscopic 3D" checkbox under "Stereoscopic 3D" in the nVidia control panel:

[image: nvidia control panel screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! yeah, that was my problem. I fixed mine by opening up the nVidia control panel, and unchecked "Stereoscopic 3D"->"Set up steroscopic D"->"Enable steroscopic 3D".

Comment: same thing happened to me when I was playing hearthstone. I was confused for a little while, then I decided to check the nvidia control panel

Comment: I had the same problem, but since stereoscopy is set to red/blue on my PC, I noticed right away in Rome 2, when everything was tinted in red. After I had fixed it, I thought it might be due to installing a driver update. Didn't know it was actually the 8->8.1 upgrade that did this.

Comment: @kalina yeah, that's a good image. Easier than uninstalling the stereoscopic 3d drivers.

Comment: I always regret upgrading windows ...

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the latest Nvidia driver for my GTX 680 and that solved the problem - also added the stereoscopic option that was not previously there.  The game it was happening on was Mass Effect.

Comment: Hmm, I had just downloaded the latest drivers, maybe this is a newer set?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Black Ops 2, but I didn't have the Stereoscopic 3D option in the nVidia control panel, so I simply uninstalled the 3d drivers in add/remove programs.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Warframe where it was in 3D settings, i just turned off the 3D setting now it runs normally.